# Stop image flickering in a ajax timer

Tags: asp.net

I have looked around but everyone seems to point towards javascript.  Being an asp.net c# server side devloper it is not something i am comfortable with.

I have this in my asp.net markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upVideo" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Enabled="False" Interval="100" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/img00001.jpg" Width="352"
Height="288" />
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and i have this in my codebehind to display a 'video' of 28 frames:

```
private void SetImageUrl()
{
int _index = Convert.ToInt16(Session["FrameIndex"]);
_index++;
if (_index == 29)
{
_index = 0;
}
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/img000" + _index.ToString("00") + ".jpg";
Session["FrameIndex"] = _index;
}


protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
SetImageUrl();
}
catch { }
}
```

It works but there is that dreaded 'flicker'. Has anyone come up with a fix for this at all?

thanks..

Comment: I'm afraid the fix is to use Javascript! I'd recommend creating a CSS sprite which contains all of your frames, setting it as the background on a div and animating the background position offset. That way it will load in one request and you will have no flicker. You can use a framework like http://spritely.net/ which will help you out a lot.

Comment: Hi, thank you.  I am looking into this as this is the way to go.  Final thing, in our opinion would that be an upper limit to the number of frames i could use in a sprite?

Comment: No problem. If my comment helped please upvote it;) It kind of depends on your scenario I suppose (really what is the file size of the image for the sprite you need and what kind of network connection do your end users have?) You can probably encode your sprite as a JPEG and set the compression ratio to reduce bandwidth some more. Hope that helps

Comment: geedubb, have you used the spritely.net framework?  I cannot see how to use it if i have 15 frames width by 15 frames height.  It just plays the 1st row...

Comment: It looks like spritely doesn't support vertical CSS sprites. You have to arrange your frames horizontally I'm afraid